# Excel Reporting Funtions

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

I have a training matrix with Company Organisational Chart in first few columns *e.g. Unit Departments and Position Titles in first two columns on left of worksheet(approx 1100 positions in Company)*, and along Row 2 at top of worksheet, in separate columns, are Training module names *e.g. "Induction Training", "Fire Awareness Training*.

Where a position requires training, an "x" is placed at the intersecting point *(e.g. Row 11, Column BA)*.  I would like excel to report the names of all modules required for a position (row) if selected on a dashboard report.

I've set up a pivot table and some slicers for my dashboard and can get the Unit/Position Title/Total number of Training Modules to link, but cannot get excel to report the names of the Training Modules for the role I select on the dashboard.

Does anyone know if what I'm trying to achieve is at all possible?

Comment: Please post some sample data and alsowhat you've achieved so far.

Comment: Thank you. What is best way to present data for you? My Dashboard is linked to a pivot which includes Unit Name, Role Title, Position Title and Total Applications (or training modules required). At this point, I've created a slicer of all training Application names and was trying to link it to the pivot.

Answer (score 0):

For getting a flexible Pivot table you have first to reshape your data source in a tabular way.

Having your data entry in the form you described, is suboptimal for pivoting

```
 Unit Department      Position Title      Training A      Training B      Training ...
 ---------------      --------------      ----------      ----------      ------------
```

Your data source should look like this

```
 Unit Department      Position Title      Training Name       Training Required
 ---------------      --------------      -------------       -----------------
```

With a Pivot having the Position Title as filter (or slicer), you will get all training (as row), by department (as column) and the according count (with training required for instance).

If you want to keep your data input table as it is, you can reshape it using Power Query for unpivoting the source in order to get the better suitable second table (as data source for the Pivot). See this answer [here](https://superuser.com/a/1065979/583258) for performing this step.